# Need help with MySql query

Tags: mysql

I want to delete all records from `wp_usermeta` with `user_id` whose `meta_value` is "tonetone" which is spam accounts.

As you know already, there are many records with one `user_id` in `wp_usermeta`. I tried like this but doesn't work. Thanks to anyone who can show me the way.

> All I want to do is delete all records
>   with that user_id but the common value
>   all I can get is "tonetone"

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = "tonetone")
```

[image]

Comment: What does this return? DB structure? Mysql error? Are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use phpmyadmin and got this >>> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_usermeta' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You have to apply my advice even though someone think I'm under drugs. In order to avoid error 1093 you have to use a subquery like I've done. Apply correct field to your specific table

Comment: So what you want is to delete every row on that table or just the one with `meta_value` = `tonetone`?

Comment: @nick, I tried yr advice but got this >>  0 row(s) deleted. ( Query took 0.5661 sec )

Comment: I've modified my answer according to your table. However it seems to me that Miky Dinescu's query does exactly what you want. I've done the things more difficult of what they are.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. It does the same as your accepted answer but without the need to create a temporary table. Generally, with SQL it's better practice to avoid creating auxiliary tables if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete users where any of the records for that user has tonetone as a meta_value, you can do this:

**CREATE TABLE wp_usermeta_users_to_delete

( user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );

INSERT INTO wp_usermeta_users_to_delete

SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM wp_usermeta

WHERE meta_value = "tonetone";

DELETE A.* FROM wp_usermeta A INNER JOIN wp_usermeta_users_to_delete B USING (user_id);

DROP TABLE wp_usermeta_users_to_delete;**

Comment: Wait. I just realized, you want to delete userid's that have tonetone in any of its records. BRB...

Comment: Yes Rolando, it's what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this >> #1109 - Unknown table 'wp_usermeta' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING (user_id)' at line 1

Comment: Wow.. I don't know what to say but it really really works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    delete from wp_usermeta where umeta_id in (select * from (select umeta_id from wp_usermeta where meta_value = "tonetone") as t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will delete ALL records from the table `wp_usermeta` which have the field `meta_value` set to *tonetone*

```
delete wp_usermeta 
  from wp_usermeta where meta_value = 'tonetone'
```

**UPDATE**

After having seen your updated question it's clear to me what you're trying to do. The following query will delete all records for each user who has a meta_value set to 'tonetone'.

```
DELETE wp_usermeta
  FROM wp_usermeta T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = 'tonetone') T2 ON T1.user_id = T2.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks Miky but it's not what I want. As I explained, there are more than one record with same user_id in wp_usermeta. If I run this sql, it'll only delete on row of a user_id.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? This query will delete all records from the table `wp_usermeta` which have the meta_value = 'tonetone'. Have you tried running this query?

Comment: I've uploaded the image and as you can see, user_id has more than one record and meta_value = "tonetone" is just one row. All I want to do is delete all rows of that user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
#1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_usermeta' for update in FROM clause
```

As documented here : [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) you cannot "modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part". The following should work:

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = 'tonetone'
```

Or to correct your query a little bit:

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = "tonetone")
```

But it has no sense at all. You basically check for a comparison in `user_id` while what you really want to check it the field of `meta_value`.

Check the first query and let me know.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the image I recently updated? It'll make u clearly understand what I want to do.